# Delphi FMX stringgrid cell does not show checkboxes

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, stringgrid

Using Delphi 11.1 the application is of the FMX (FireMonkey) type.
I have a `TStringgrid` with a `TCheckColumn`.
The grid does not show the checkbox.
If I click two times on the cell the state changes and the the box is shown, after that it behaves normally.

I set the value of a cell in code like

`StringGrid1.Cells[CHECKBOX_COLUMN, iIndex]:= BoolToStr(False);`

Reading like

`boMyBoolean := StringGrid1.Cells[CHECKBOX_COLUMN, 0].ToBoolean;`

Help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BoolToStr has two arguments:

```
function BoolToStr(B: Boolean; UseBoolStrs: Boolean = False): string;
```

If you call it with `UseBoolStrs = True` then the `StringGrid` reacts as you expect:

E.g. during `FormCreate`:

```
procedure TForm5.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  StringGrid1.Cells[0, 1] := BoolToStr(False, True);
  StringGrid1.Cells[1, 1] := BoolToStr(False, True);
end;
```

where the first column is a `TCheckColumn` and the second column is a `TStringColumn` shows

[image]

And reacts as you expect it to, to subsequent changes.